# Unable to disambiguate Document interface and Document var

Tags: typescript

TypeScript 2.7.2 yields a rather surprising error.

```
const handleKeyDown = (document: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent): any => {
  switch (ev.keyCode) {
    case 78: // N
      this.someOtherFunction();
      console.log("Pressed key N");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
};

document.addEventListener<'keydown'>('keydown', handleKeyDown)
```

fails with

```
 error TS2345: Argument of type '(document: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any' 
is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any'.
```

which is at odds with the [Comparing two functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) section of the TypeScript documentation.

However, on further investigation, the `handleKeyDown`'s `Document` refers to `interface Document` in `lib.dom.d.ts`, whereas, the `addEventListener`'s `Document` refers to

```
declare var Document: {
  prototype: Document;
  new(): Document;
};
```

also in `lib.dom.d.ts`.

How do I get this to typecheck?

EDIT:

```
  handleKeyDown(document: {
    prototype: Document;
    new: () => Document
  }, ev: KeyboardEvent) { ...
```

does not typecheck either, with

```
[ts] Argument of type '(document: { prototype: Document; new: () => Document; }, ev: KeyboardEvent) => void' 
is not assignable to parameter of type '(this: Document, ev: KeyboardEvent) => any'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `addEventListener` is declared as a function that takes event as its first argument, and you are passing it a function that takes two arguments, first of which is of wrong type - `Document`. The correct way to declare it is

```
const handleKeyDown = (ev: KeyboardEvent): any => {
  switch (ev.keyCode) {
    case 78: // N
      this.someOtherFunction();
      console.log("Pressed key N");
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
};


document.addEventListener<'keydown'>('keydown', handleKeyDown)
```

`this: Document` in `addEventListener` declaration is not an argument, it's just a way to declare type of `this` when the function is called, but since `handleKeyDown` is an arrow functin, `this` in it refers to `this` in enclosing context, not to the document anyway.